# trouble with numpy power function arguments

Tags: python, numpy

I can't figure out what's wrong with this section of code.

```
def f1_x(xvec):
    yvec = 1/(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.power(np.exp,(np.power(xvec,2)/4))
    print(yvec)
    return yvec
```

Every time I attempt to run the line, it outputs:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'numpy.ufunc' and 'float'
```

Everything else in the code is working like a charm to my knowledge, just this little block is giving me trouble.

P.S., the function I am attempting to describe is

```
f(x)=1/(√2π)*e^(-(x)^2/(4)),
```

Comment: np.exp is a function

Comment: It should be `np.exp(np.power(...))`

Comment: You want `yvec = 1/(np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-np.power(xvec,2)/4))

Comment: `numpy.exp` is a function, not Euler's number.

Comment: (Also you dropped a minus sign.)